# XML won't get validated using two (2) tables in xml - two XMLs into one ? 

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

Given the next XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hotels SYSTEM "travel.dtd">
<hotels>
    <general>
        <city>MoscowCity</city>
        <address>Sherman23</address>
        <phone>423423432423</phone>
        <hotelDetails>
            <hotel_code>1</hotel_code>
            <hotel_rank>3</hotel_rank>
            <hotel_name>Jacky</hotel_name>
        </hotelDetails>
    </general>
</hotels>

<!DOCTYPE guests SYSTEM "travel.dtd">   // HERE Validation problem 
<guests>
    <guest>
            <id>00000001-0</id>
            <guestDetails>
                <name>Jones</name>
                <city>SomewhereOnlyWeKnow</city>
                <address>NiceStreet</address>
                <state>NiceState</state>
            </guestDetails>
    </guest>
</guests>
```

And its DTD file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!ELEMENT hotels (general+)>
<!ELEMENT general (city, address, phone, hotelDetails)>
<!ELEMENT hotelDetails (hotel_code, hotel_rank, hotel_name)>
<!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT hotel_rank (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT phone (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT hotel_code (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT hotel_name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT guests (guest+)>
<!ELEMENT guest (id, guestDetails)>
<!ELEMENT guestDetails (name, city, address, state)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT state (#PCDATA)>
```

The file won't get validated , and XMLspy output is :

```
 Character 'D' is grammatically unexpected
```

Any idea what that means ?

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently it means you took two XML files and saved them as one file, resulting in invalid XML, with two root nodes and two doctypes, while only one root node is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can have two root elements in one XML document. As far as I know this means your XML is not well-formed, hence the error message after the closing tag of the first root element.

Comment: I'm requested to have only one XML file for both tables, therefore I cannot split them into two separated XMLs. No other way to do that ? thanks

Comment: The only way I can think of is to put the two tables inside a new root element, but of course you would have to add that to the DTD to make it a valid XML document.

Comment: Okay ,can you please give me an example of explain how to do that ?

Comment: Let's say the root element shall be <travel>, then you would need to add the line   
`<!ELEMENT travel (hotels|guests)+>`   
to the DTD. 
The XML would look like  
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE travel SYSTEM "travel.dtd">  
<travel>  
   <hotels>  
      <!-- content -->  
   </hotels>  
  
   <guests>  
      <!-- content -->  
   </guests>`

Comment: Forgot the closing tag `</travel>` at the end of the example above.

Comment: I've made the changes - edited my original post - but the code still won't get validated , can you please give me a feedback  ? 10x.

Comment: You have to remove the comment tags (`<!--` and `-->`) in your XML. Additionally, the definition for the element <id> is missing in your DTD. Add the line `<!ELEMENT id (#PCDATA)>` to the DTD and it should be fine.